# Jasper Report Image plainWidth()F error

Tags: jasper-reports

I am getting this error at my tomcat server 6 using iReport 1.3.0, iTest 2.1.0, jasper libraies jasperreports-1.2.8-javaflow.jar

some of forum told use iText jar lates, i also replace with latest and clean project and rebuild but still getting same problem.

```
Error : 
**SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.Image.plainWidth()F
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1046)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:581)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:549)**
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey no worries, i have solved it, its iText jar version incompatibility.

I have two iText.2.1.0.jar and iText.1.3.1.jar. i removed iText.2.1.0.jar.

Answer (score 1):

For those using the amazing [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) with Maven and getting this same error, just change the version of the library from an old one (in my case `R8pre2`) to a new one (in my case, `R8`):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
    <version>R8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Brandizzi did this the correct way. I was previously on iText 2.0.8. Moved my org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer version to R8 and the issue was resolved.